# In DataPrep, sum a set of many columns or values in an object

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep, wrangle

I have a DataPrep dataset which contains a series of ~10 columns, each of which indicates whether or not a particular brochure was selected:

```
BRO_AF    BRO_SAF    BRO_SE   ...
1                    1
1         1
                     1
```

I'd like to sum/count these values into a `BrochuresSelected` column.

I was hoping to use `ADD` with a column range (ie `BRO_AF~BRO_ITA`), but `ADD` only takes two numbers.

I can't use `COUNT`, as it counts rows not columns.

I can use `NEST` to create a column storing a `map` or `array` of brochures, but there doesn't seem to be a function for adding these. I can't use `ARRAYLEN` on this column, as even empty columns are represented in the column (eg `["1","","","","",""]` would have an array length of six, not one).

Has anyone solved a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the column names, you can use the `+` operator in a derive transform. For example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Lars , that's a nice and simple way of doing it. I think I'd gone too far down the rabbit hole with column ranges, etc and was overthinking it!